# Atlas of finite groups, Character table of automorphism group of sporadic group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, sporadic-groups

I am consulting ATLAS of finite group for character table of Automorphism Group of sporadic group.

I am reading from *Inverse Galois Theory* by G. Malle

[image]
[image]

**Let me start with $G=M_{12}$**

This(image attached) is from ATLAS page of $G=M_{12}$, It's automorphism group is $G.2$

Now in the proposition we have taken conjugacy class triple $(2C,3A,12A)$, but see the block(character table) for $G.2$ on right hand side top, $2C$ and $12A$ are there but there is no $3A$ in that block.

**What is the explanation ?**

**In the character table of $G.2$ there is no conjugacy class of type $3A$ but in proposition he taken the triple $(2C,3A,12A)$.**

In all other cases, I am encountering the same kind of  problem, eg. In $Aut(M_{22}), Aut(J_{2})$, etc

Kindly sort me out.
[image]

**------------------------Edits ----------------------------**
Page 21, The ATLAS

[image]

Comment: I can see a 3A - it's the fourth column of character entries  from the left.

Comment: @DerekHolt But it is not in the character table of $G.2$

Comment: What is G, here? I would have guessed it's M12 itself.

Comment: @DavidRoberts yes, right. Thanks for pointing out, It is confusing. Let me edit the question.

Comment: This is just a guess, but perhaps you haven't realised that the character table for $G.2$ **includes** the character table for $G$. So that conjugacy class 3A for $G$ that Derek mentioned is also a conjugacy class for $G.2$. Would that clarify things?

Comment: @NickGill But then how one account for the fact that $\chi_{3}$ is not even  defined for conjugacy class of type $2C,4C,4D$, etc. (See the empty line.) That table shows(I guess) that out of 15 irreducible character of G, all but $\chi_{3},\chi_{5},\chi_{10},$ are irreducible character of $G.2$

Comment: I suggest you read Section 7 of the ATLAS introduction which tells you how to interpret this sort of (apparently) empty line. Look at, for instance Subsection 15 of that section entitled *The detachment of columns for a group $G.2$*.

Comment: $\chi_2+\chi_3$ is a single character of $M_{12}.2$, induced from the character $\chi_2$ (or $\chi_3$) of $M_{12}$. It's value is $0$ on elements not in $M_{12}$.

Comment: You should also be aware  that some pairs of conjugacy classes of $M_{12}$ fuse into a single class of $M_{12}.2$. These pairs are (4A,4B), (8A,8B), and (11A,11B).

Comment: I got it know, Thanks, Nick, Derek for the help.

Comment: It's a pleasure, glad I could help.

Comment: Nowadays it is maybe a little bit easier to ask GAP to print that character table for you: `ct:= CharacterTable( "M12.2" );; Display( ct );` Use `AtlasClassNames( ct );` to get the names of the conjugacy classes in the Atlas. So you don't have to derive yourself the character table from the table of $M_{12}$ and information on fusion of classes/ extension of characters, like in the printed Atlas.

Comment: @FriederLadisch Can I compute the conjugacy class representative of "M12.2"  through some command.  I know how to find order of class representative and size of conjugacy class but Is there some command by which I can explicitly write the class representative.

Comment: Well, if I say `ct:= CharacterTable( "M12.2" );`, then `ct` is a table from the Character Table Library of GAP, which has no access to the group ($M_{12}.2$ in this case), and so you can't get class representatives. So you first have to construct "M12.2" as a group, and then tell GAP that `ct` is the table of that group. See Section 71.6 of the GAP manual.